# Trouble filling a c++ array, only last item at every index

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, ifstream, cout

Firstly, this is for a class so there are limitations on what we can and can't do, plus I am extremely new to c++ and programming in general, so that is why the code is probably a little crap.

I am at my wits end trying to understand why when I display the item_list using the first set of cout lines within the first for loop, it displays each individual item as it should be (its a list of skyrim ingredients and their effects).

However, when the second for loop executes, the item_list is filled with nothing but the last item that should have been inserted (wisp wrappings and their effects).

Even just pointing me in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated :)

cheers

```
int client::fill_list(int size_in, int h1size, int h2size)
{
    char temp[ASIZE] = {'\0'};
    int j = 0;
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("test.txt");

    if(ifile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size_in; ++i)
        {    
            if(ifile.good())
            {       
                j = 0;
                do
                {                   
                    temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                    ++j;
                }while(ifile.peek() != '*');
                temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                copy(client_item.name, temp, j);
            }


            if(ifile.good())
            {
                j = 0;
                do
                {                   
                    temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                    ++j;
                }while(ifile.peek() != '*');
                temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                copy(client_item.effect1, temp, j);
            }

            if(ifile.good())
            {
                j = 0;
                do
                {                   
                    temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                    ++j;
                }while(ifile.peek() != '*');
                temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                copy(client_item.effect2, temp, j);
            }

            if(ifile.good())
            {
                j = 0;
                do
                {                   
                    temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                    ++j;
                }while(ifile.peek() != '*');
                temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                copy(client_item.effect3, temp, j);
            }

            if(ifile.good())
            {
                j = 0;
                do
                {                   
                    temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                    ++j;
                }while(ifile.peek() != '*');
                temp[j] = char(ifile.get());
                copy(client_item.effect4, temp, j);
            }
            reference.into_list(i,client_item);
        cout << reference.item_list[i].name;
        cout << reference.item_list[i].effect1;
        cout << reference.item_list[i].effect2;
        cout << reference.item_list[i].effect3;
        cout << reference.item_list[i].effect4;
        getchar();
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
    {
        cout << reference.item_list[k].name;
        cout << reference.item_list[k].effect1;
        cout << reference.item_list[k].effect2;
        cout << reference.item_list[k].effect3;
        cout << reference.item_list[k].effect4;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

...

```
int table::into_list(int index, item&item_in)
{
    if(index < SIZE)
    {
        item_list[index] = item_in;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

...
Header for the table class

```
#include "hash.h"

class table
{
public:
    table()
    {
        item_list = new item [SIZE];
    }
    ~table();
    int fill(item*);
    int insert(item&, nHash&);
    int insert(item&, eHash&, int);
    int retrieve(char*,item*,int);
    int remove(int,item&);
    int remove(int);
    int check_hash(int,int,int);
    int keygen(char*, int);
    int from_list(int, item&);
    int into_list(int, item&);

//private:
    item * item_list;
    nHash name_table;
    eHash ef1_table;
    eHash ef2_table;
    eHash ef3_table;
    eHash ef4_table;
};
```

....
Beginning of main

```
#include "client.h"

int main()
{
    client program;

    program.fill_list(SIZE,HNSIZE,HESIZE);

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        cout << program.reference.item_list[i].name;
        cout << program.reference.item_list[i].effect1 << endl;
        cout << program.reference.item_list[i].effect2 << endl;
        cout << program.reference.item_list[i].effect3 << endl;
        cout << program.reference.item_list[i].effect4 << endl;
    }
```

....

item header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int ASIZE = 30;
const int SIZE = 92;
const int HNSIZE = 41;
const int HESIZE = 17;

struct item
{
    item();
    ~item();
    char * name;
    char * effect1;
    char * effect2;
    char * effect3;
    char * effect4;
    int count;
    //int keygen(int,int);
    /*int name_key;
    int ef1_key;
    int ef2_key;
    int ef3_key;
    int ef4_key;*/
};
```

Comment: Your programming class integrates Skyrim exercises? Where do I sign up?

Comment: Is `reference.item_list[k]` performing some sort of `pop_back(); pop();` operation using vectors or something? What is the type of `reference_item`?

Comment: It might be useful to see more of the code involving `reference`: the `into_list` method, type of `item_list`, etc.

Comment: @chris It's great until the whole Clockwork Orange thing.  Now every time I goto craft a potion my eyes bleed.

Comment: @Drise reference is an instance of class table, with item_list as a member (that I have public right now for ease of access), item_list is a pointer to an array of items.  Item is a struct with name, and effects as char pointers.

Comment: @user1404053 Being reminded of code makes your eyes bleed? It's practically a lullaby for me...

Comment: @user1404053 Could you post the code snippet? Describing it is somewhat hard to see. Also, class `table`?

Comment: into_list just copies the client_item into the table's list by index.

Comment: @Drise lol, haven't quite gotten to that lullaby point...  It's still a bit like being in a foreign country and needing directions

Comment: I'm more interested to see what happens when you access the items. If they get popped out of the container, that may be your answer. I can't know unless you can show me the table class and its implementation. Nothing seems out of place with your code, so I'm thinking its somewhere in the class.

Comment: Seeing what reference is, what item_list is, etc. would be good. Also a reduced example that is complete and compilable but which exhibits the issue would be good. My suspicion is that `reference.item_list[0,1,2,3...]` all refer to the same object. The first loop prints that one object out repeatedly, but you're updating it each iteration so you get different results for each iteration. But the second loop prints out the item repeatedly without modifying it on each iteration. You can test this by making a modification to the item at one index and then checking the value from another index.

Comment: Why are you using `size_in` for the first loop, and `SIZE` for the second? Try printing out the value of `i` and `k` in those loops, and see what they are, and if they are what you are expecting.

Comment: @Drise, post-increment may be in certain books and such, but using pre-incrementing is a good habit, as it can save you making a sometimes-expensive copy.

Comment: my version using the standard library: http://ideone.com/pQOLN from your origional code.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's somewhat hard to follow... It seems more likely to confuse the OP, since he/she mentioned he/she is "extremely new to c++ and programming in general"... Maybe I'm just being thick, but I can't find any use for that comment. Also note the fact that this is for a class, and most classes generally tend to **greatly** restrict what is and is not allowed. And from what I've seen in low-level c++ classes, they **never** discuss `iterator`s or `vector`s.

Comment: @Drise: Mostly that there exists a short (though unintuitive) way.  I've seen a lot of new programmers say they'll give up on C++ because doing anything with IO takes thousands of lines, because they don't know that there _is_ an elegant way.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: C++ is hardly my favorite for IO, but that is quite clean.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah, even if I understood, we are severely limited in what we can and can't do.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that part of the problem is how you make copies of `client_item` here:

```
reference.into_list(i,client_item);
```

This just assigns `client_item` to `item_list` like so:

```
item_list[index] = item_in;
```

...but since `item` is defined like this:

```
struct item
{
    item();
    ~item();
    char * name;
    char * effect1;
    ...
```

...all of the `item`s in `item_list` will have pointers (like `name`, etc.) that point to the same memory as the memory in `client_item`.

For example, after each assignment, the pointers `item_list[index].name` and `item_in.name` will have the same value.  (You can check that by printing both pointers, if you're curious.)  Since they both point to the same memory, if you change what's stored at that memory, both objects will appear to change at the same time.

That means that subsequent changes to `client_item` -- like copying a new string into one of the places that it points -- will affect all of the saved items as well.

Comment: That sounds like the most sane answer to me.

Comment: Bah! That was quite obvious, how did I miss that?

Comment: And there it is!  Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: So I gather I need to create a new function or modify the function to create new char arrays of the appropriate size and then copy the client data array by array instead of as a struct

Comment: @user1404053: that sounds reasonable.